# javascript associative array type of returned data

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
delta = {
    "north": [-1,  0, -1, -1, -1,  1],
    "south": [ 1,  0,  1  -1,  1,  1],
    "east":  [ 0, -1,  0, -1,  0,  1],
    "west":  [ 0,  1,  0,  1,  0, -1]
 }
traceArray = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        console.log('array() - n,' + i + ' colDelta = ' + typeof this.delta['north'][i]);
        console.log('array() - s,' + i + ' colDelta = ' + typeof this.delta['south'][i]);
        console.log('array() - e,' + i + ' colDelta = ' + typeof this.delta['east'][i]);
        console.log('array() - w,' + i + ' colDelta = ' + typeof this.delta['west'][i]);
    }
}
```

I'm using an associative array with four string keys, each associated data component is a 6 element, numeric array. When accessed, 23 of the elements return numeric values, one element consistently returns an undefined value. The array definition is probably at fault, please point me at the error.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There is a typo, which is making it just 5 elements for `delta.south`

```
 delta = {
    "north": [-1,  0, -1, -1, -1,  1],
    "south": [ 1,  0,  1,  -1,  1,  1],  // there was a comma missing after 2nd 1
    "east":  [ 0, -1,  0, -1,  0,  1],
    "west":  [ 0,  1,  0,  1,  0, -1]
 }
```

What is happening is since there is no `,` it is evaluating to `1 - 1 = 0`, so `delta.south[2]` is equal to `0` So there's no 6th element which you're accessing and therefore `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

```
"south": [ 1,  0,  1  -1,  1,  1],
                    ^
```

You missed a comma here, so there's only 5 elements in this array. That's why you get `undefined` when trying to read the 6th element.

Answer (score 0):

It's because one comma is missed:

```
delta = {
    "north": [-1,  0, -1, -1, -1,  1],
    "south": [ 1,  0,  1  -1,  1,  1], // <- check it here
    "east":  [ 0, -1,  0, -1,  0,  1],
    "west":  [ 0,  1,  0,  1,  0, -1]
 }
```

So, you get valid js expression `1-1` in your delta.south[2], which is 0;